# How to match pattern based on a field value in the file and replace it?

Tags: regex, bash, scripting

I have a text file of the following format:

```
label1-label1/label2 label1
label3-label3/label4 label3
label5-label5/label6 label5
```

I want to generate an output of the following format:

```
label1/label2
label3/label4
label5/label6
```

I cannot use either `'-'` or `'/'` as delimiters because they are a part of the label as well.

I have tried using `awk` and `sed` commands to extract `$1` and `$2` from the file, but not able to figure out how to provide `$2` as the original pattern to be replaced from `$1`.

I thought of using `$2` (label1) to match pattern in `$1` (label1-label1/label2) and trim it to get the result, label1/label2, but didn't know how to do it.

Ex:
Label1: United-States, Label2: New-York

Input:-

```
United-States-United-States/New-York United-States
```

Output:-

```
United-States/New-York
```

Comment: The regex is simple `([^\/]+)-\1\/(\S+)` Then you have it in $1 and $2 https://regex101.com/r/75qv7K/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/y6jHHo/1

Comment: Try `sed -E 's,^(.*)-\1/(.*) (.*)$,\1/\2,'`, see https://ideone.com/QceUjv

Comment: is it works? https://regex101.com/r/WKvdCx/1

Answer (score 0):

here a solution in pure bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    attachment="${line##* }"                  # get last part of line
    length="${#attachment}"                   # length of last part
    printf "%s\n" "${line:length+1:-length}"  # print line, shorten the start/end by last part
done < file.txt
```

**input (file.txt)**

```
label1-label1/label2 label1
label3-label3/label4 label3
label5-label5/label6 label5
United-States-United-States/New-York United-States
United/States/United/States/New-York United/States
United-States-United-States-New-York United-States
United$States$United$States$New$York United$States
United*States*United*States*New*York United*States
```

**output**

```
label1/label2 
label3/label4 
label5/label6 
United-States/New-York 
United/States/New-York 
United-States-New-York 
United$States$New$York 
United*States*New*York
```

Comment: Shouldn't lines 5, 6, 7 and 8 be ignored as they are the wrong format?

Answer (score 0):

Great minds think alike... While you can use an `awk` split, it is probably just as easy to use a `while` loop to read the information from your file and the separate the first combination of the wanted data into `label1` and `label2` using simple *parameter expansions* trimming from the `<-end` and then `beginning->` up to the `'/'` character that separates them. At that point, you simply need to take `1/2 length + 1` of `label1` and then combine it with the saved `label2` for your desired string.

Something similar to:

```
while read -r label stuff; do   ## read combined label, ignore 2nd string stuff
    l1="${label%/*}"            ## isolate label1 (l1)
    l2="${label#*/}"            ## isolate label2 (l2)
    l1=${l1:$((${#l1}/2+1))}    ## take len/2+1 of l1
    echo "$l1/$l2"              ## put shortened l1 and l2 together
done < file
```

**Example Input File**

Using your input file and example shown in a file:

```
$ cat file
label1-label1/label2 label1
label3-label3/label4 label3
label5-label5/label6 label5
United-States-United-States/New-York United-States
```

**Example Use/Output**

Simply selecting and using middle-mouse paste in the terminal in the directory where `file` is located provides the following desired output:

```
$ while read -r label stuff; do   ## read combined label, ignore 2nd string stuff
>     l1="${label%/*}"            ## isolate label1 (l1)
>     l2="${label#*/}"            ## isolate label2 (l2)
>     l1=${l1:$((${#l1}/2+1))}    ## take len/2+1 of l1
>     echo "$l1/$l2"              ## put shortened l1 and l2 together
> done < file
label1/label2
label3/label4
label5/label6
United-States/New-York
```

(**note:** [UtLox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11178750/utlox) was the first answer here, so give primacy whatever deference it is due, it is essentially the same approach, just a different approach on where the length, division and addition occur)

Probably the easiest approach here is if you can guarantee the last part of the line with always be `label1`. If that is valid given your file, then you simply need a single parameter expansion to output the desired result, e.g.

```
while read -r label l1; do              ## read both parts of line
    echo "$l1/${label#*/}"              ## put l1 with trimmed label
done < file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ while read -r label l1; do              ## read both parts of line
>     echo "$l1/${label#*/}"              ## put l1 with trimmed label
> done < file
label1/label2
label3/label4
label5/label6
United-States/New-York
```

It is just a simpler way to do it if the 2nd part of each line is always going to be your `label1` (no need to split what comes before the `'/'`)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)-\1\/\(.*\) \1$/\1\/\2/' file
```

This matches:

- start of line
- followed by anything
- followed by hyphen
- followed by the first anything
- followed by forward slash
- followed by a second, possibly different, anything
- followed by a space
- followed by the first anything
- followed by end of line

and replaces it with:

- the first anything
- followed by a forward slash
- followed by the second anything

Lines that don't match are output unchanged.

To not output if the input has wrong format:

```
sed '/^\(.*\)-\1\/\(.*\) \1$/!d; s//\1\/\2/' file
```

- delete line if not correct format
- otherwise perform the substitution